# Approximation with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, approximation

I am trying to approximate function with keras model, that has only one hidden layer and whatever I do - I can't reach necessary result.

I'm trying to do it with following code

```
from __future__ import print_function
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam

from LABS.ZeroLab import E_Function as dataset5

train_size = 2000

# 2 model and data initializing
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = dataset5.load_data(train_size=train_size, show=True)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(50, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='he_uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='he_uniform', activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mae', metrics=['mae'])

history = model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=20, epochs=10000, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=1)
```

[It's function that loads from dataset5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX2f5.png)

[It's comparison of model prediction with testing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zJT9.png)

I tryied to fit this network with different optimizers and neurons number (from 50 to 300), but result was the same.

What should I change?

Comment: Is the dataset available somewherE?

Comment: Are you supposed to be using a standard NN? The data looks like a time-series so I'd use a RNN or something but I just want to make sure. I'm not surprised it's predicting the middle of the data because that's essentially what it's optimized to do

Comment: @Ian Quah yes, I supposed to use standart NN. I tryied to approximate this function with NN, that has 2 hidden layers and result was much better.
You can check it by the following links
https://github.com/DanilaEremenko/NeuralNetwork/blob/demo/LABS/SecondLab/Adam/C_2Adam_10000_0.001_80_40_0.0195/compare.png

My friend uses matlab and he approximated  this function with 1 hidden layer and very small loss,using same structure of NN.

Comment: @sdcbr you can see the vizualization of dataset here 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX2f5.png

Answer (score 0):

I found solution! The main issue was train data. I forgot to shuffle x_train and y_train before fitting.
I approximated it with 2 hidden layers succesfully, but I still can't to approximate it with 1 hidden layer.